# Mathematica 3d plot of a function of a function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to make a 3d plot of a function that takes as a variable a function of another variable.

The whole thing is complicated by the fact that my functions are nested piecewise functions

here is my code:

```
phi0=Function[u,1.21*10^-6/((u/10^44.25)^1.01 + (u/10^44.25)^2.38)][Lx]
zc=Function[v,Piecewise[{{2.49,v>=10^45.74},{2.49*(v/10^45.74)^0.2,v<10^45.74}}]][Lx]

e=Function[uu,Piecewise[{{(1+uu)^4.62,uu<=zc},{(1+zc)^4.62*((1+uu)/(1+zc))^-1.15,uu>zc}}]][z]

Plot3D[e[z,Lx],{z,0,7},{Lx,10^42,10^47}, PlotRange->Full]
```

but it is not plotting anything, and I am not sure of what to do

EDIT:

thanks, for the hint, I think I solved it this way. It is not giving me any error, but it is taking a lot of time to evaluate the result even in one single point... do you think it is normal?

```
phizero[Lx_] := 1.21/10^6/((Lx/10^44.25)^1.01 + (Lx/10^44.25)^2.38)

zc[Lx_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2.49, Lx >= 10^45.74}, {2.49*(Lx/10^45.74)^0.2, 
    Lx < 10^45.74}}]

e[z_, Lx_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(1 + z)^4.62, 
    z <= zc[Lx]}, {(1 + zc[Lx])^4.62*((1 + z)/(1 + zc[Lx]))^-1.15, 
    z > zc[Lx]}}]

phi[z_, Lx_] := phizero[Lx]*e[z, Lx]

(*D[phi[z,Lx],Lx]:=Lx*phi[z,Lx]*)

p[z_, Lx_] = Integrate[Lx*phi[z, Lx], Lx]
p[4, 10^44]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is taking a long time because it works hard to symbolically integrate the function. It takes a while just to learn it cant be done. -- use NIntegrate for numerical integration.  Here is a stab at it.. notice as a good habit i leave out the floating point values from the expressions until really needed:

```
 constants = {c1 -> 10^45.74, c2 -> 10^44.25, c3 -> 2.49, c4 -> 4.62, 
   c5 -> 2.38, c6 -> 0.2, c7 -> 1.21/10^6, c8 -> -1.15, c9 -> 1.01}
phizero[Lx_] := c7/((Lx/c2)^c9 + (Lx/c2)^c5)
zc[Lx_] := Piecewise[{{c3, Lx >= c1}, {c3 (Lx/c1)^c6, Lx < c1}}]
e[z_, Lx_] := 
      Piecewise[{{(1 + z)^c4, 
           z <= zc[Lx]}, {(1 + zc[Lx])^c4 ((1 + z)/(1 + zc[Lx]))^c8, 
           z > zc[Lx]}}]
phi[z_, Lx_] := phizero[Lx] e[z, Lx]
p[z_, L1_, L2_] := NIntegrate[Lx phi[z, Lx] /. constants, {Lx, L1, L2}]
p[4, 10^42, 10^47]
```

quickly returns:

```
   (* ~7 10^84 *)
```

Comment: I think george is right, his solution works (thanks also for having taught me how to set up constants). 
It is not giving me the answer i was expecting (by something like 90 orders of magnitude), so I need to figure out were I screwed up.

In the help section it is written not to thank people for the answers, but screw them, I would have lost days without you, so thanks a lot, and thanks a lot also to Bill for the hints on how to improve my code (I badly needed them as a total beginner). 

I would vote up both but I don't have the 15 reputation required, I will as soon as I have them

Answer (score 1):

First, Function works like this:

```
In[1]:= q = Function[x, x^2];
In[2]:= q[4]
Out[2]= 16
```

so lose the [var] that you have at the end of each of your Function definitions.
You could also do

```
q[x_]:= x^2
```

and skip the use of Function[] if that would be simpler.

Next, you define the function e to accept a single argument, but then you give it two arguments when you use it inside your Plot3D. So you need to figure out what your definition of the function e should be and I can't even guess how to do that.

Comment: second that, rewrite it without explicit use of Function[]

Comment: Congratulations. You seem to have made a lot more progress from your first post to your edit with only a couple of hints.  I am worried about your Integrate. You are doing Integrate with the constant 10^44 for the second argument and Integrate expects a variable there, not a constant. Fix that and you should see an instant answer.

Comment: notice its not a delayed function def, so the integration is done symbolically before the call with numeric arguments. saimon i suspect you want a definite integral..